# Priority order of a look up table on python: how is that read?

Tags: python

Folks, 
I have this look up table and then, a python script that looks for those strings at the beginning of string placed between strings separated by "_"
For example, for this:  Accc_x09vbbb_Bcdddd, the script should identify x09vbbb

However, I have a question. 
Is the internal logic from python going to use first come, first serve? aka, identify "noedoe" before "noe" since this is at the beggining of the look up table or it will not. Basically, it will use the shortest string on the look at table or other way to search.

['xc0', 'x09', 'xc7', 'xz9', 'xz0', 'xx0', 'xx9', 'xga', 'xgb', 'xg9', 'cn7',
                     'x8x', 'noedoe', 'noeprf', 'noegtdon', 'noegtrf', 'noegtgrf', 'hollvc',
                     'holrf', 'holpg', 'holpll', 'holthm', 'holp00f', 'holbp00f', 'holary',
                     'pgt', 'hol', 'noe']

Comment: We can't answer questions about your code if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Instead of _describing_ your code, why don't you _post_ it.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot post it. Company guidelines. I have to modify that significantly to post.

Comment: I can potentially create one from scratch